# Page becomes 'frozen' in Chrome after commandLink with target="_blank" is pressed

Tags: java, jsf, google-chrome

Here is jsf code:

```
<h:commandLink id="previewlink" value="#{msg['report.preview']}" target="_blanc">
    <f:param name="printpreview" value="#{previewTitle}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

When I press the link new page is opened in a new tab and works fine but parent page becomes blocked (i.e. none of its commandLinks work). In Firefox everything works fine on both pages.

Any suggestions?

UPD: source in img (can't find text version in chrome)

[alt text http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/2127/source.png](http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/2127/source.png)

Comment: Can you show the actual HTML result? Is the typo in target='blanc` only here on SO? Could it be that the links are actually firing, but in a new document that you already have elsewhere on your screen?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: I really hoped that you pointed the real problem but _blank didn't help unfortunatelly

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the generated JavaScript function, you're using Sun Mojarra as JSF implementation (please mention that with more detail in the future, you could for instance also have used Apache MyFaces).

I just tried the following [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) on Tomcat 6.0.20 with Mojarra 1.2_14:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<f:view>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>SO question 2111438</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h:form id="form">
                <h:commandLink id="link" value="link" action="#{bean.action}" target="_blank">
                    <f:param name="paramname" value="paramvalue" />
                </h:commandLink>
            </h:form>
        </body>
    </html>
</f:view>
```

...with a dummy action method on a request scoped bean and it just works flawlessly on Chrome 3.0.195.38.

I however recall similar JavaScript problem with Safari which has been fixed about around Mojarra 1.2_08. Ensure that you're using the latest Mojarra version. You can get it at their [main dev site](http://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net). Hope this helps.

The full generated HTML source was by the way (slightly reformatted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 

<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>SO question 2111438</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="/playground/test.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="form" value="form" /> 
            <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">function dpf(f) {var adp = f.adp;if (adp != null) {for (var i = 0;i < adp.length;i++) {f.removeChild(adp[i]);}}};function apf(f, pvp) {var adp = new Array();f.adp = adp;var i = 0;for (k in pvp) {var p = document.createElement("input");p.type = "hidden";p.name = k;p.value = pvp[k];f.appendChild(p);adp[i++] = p;}};function jsfcljs(f, pvp, t) {apf(f, pvp);var ft = f.target;if (t) {f.target = t;}f.submit();f.target = ft;dpf(f);};</script> 
            <a id="form:link" href="#" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.getElementById('form'),{'form:link':'form:link','paramname':'paramvalue'},'_blank');}return false">link</a><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="j_id8:j_id9" /> 
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attention. I'll also try to explore this problem in a few days and write about the results.

Answer (score 0):

The target="" attribute is used for frames only or with HTML 4.01

There is famous problem with google chrome in this area.

Please try maybe with javascript - jQuery to have better cross browser compatibility.